# iPhone Objective-C Basic Example Question (about Properties)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, properties

Sorry I couldn't give a more descriptive title. My question (after looking at the code below) is what **statusText** is. Is it an IBOutlet or a UILabel? How does "@property (retain,nonatomic) UILabel *statusText" work? Does that statement mean that statusText is a property???

Thanks for answering. If there are any questions, please feel free to comment.

**Button_FunViewController.h**

```
@interface Button_Fun2ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *statusText;
}
@property (retain,nonatomic) UILabel *statusText;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed: (id)sender;
```

**Button_FunViewController.m**

```
@synthesize statusText;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed: (id)sender {
    NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ button was pressed.", title];
    statusText.text = newText;
    [newText.release];  
}
```

Comment: Based on the first 2 answers, I guess that means statusText is a UILabel not a property. Then why the "@property (retain,nonatomic) UILabel *statusText" and why doesn't that statement make it a property???

Comment: Why can't an object be a property? I.e., why can't statusText be an object of type UILabel and still be a property?

Comment: and @property is *necessary* for making it a property, but not *sufficient*.

Comment: @refulgentis why not sufficient? do you mean the necessary "@synthesize" in the .m file

Also isn't a property like a method? How can an object be a property and an object? That would make statusText and setStatusText two methods of what object. What can statusText and setStatusText be called upon? like [object setStatusText] and [object statusText];??

Comment: Dude. Relax. Read the docs if you have no clue what you're talking about, this is kind of silly, nouns are being thrown around like they mean nothing.

Synthesize creates your setter/getter. Property declares your ivar can be synthesized. The setter/getter can be accessed via dot synax or [object setProperty]/[object property].

Answer (score 2):

IBOutlet evaluates to nothing, it's just a hint to Interface Builder that it's a 'connection'.

And yes, statusText is a property then. There are three statements needed for a property (on a non-"modern runtime" system) – an ivar declaration, a `@property` statement, and a `synthesize` statement.

Answer (score 2):

`statusText` is an instance variable of type `UILabel*`.  The `IBOutlet` keyword simply makes that instance variable available to Interface Builder.

`@property` declares accessor and/or mutator methods for the given property.  It's equivalent to declaring `-statusLabel` and `-setStatusLabel:` methods.

You can use `@synthesize` to automatically implement these `-statusLabel` and `-setStatusLabel:` methods.  The `nonatomic` and `retain` keywords define the behaviour of these automatically-generated methods.

Alternatively, you can implement the `-statusLabel` and `-setStatusLabel:` methods yourself.

Comment: yes but what purpose does the "@property" declaration do? also, how do I use the property?

Comment: The purpose is to declare the publicly-accessible properties of your class.  Typically, properties correspond to private instance variables, but they don't have to.

Comment: but in this example it does nothing i guess. cause i deleted the "@property" and "@synthesize" and it still worked.

Comment: @koldfyre `@property` is simply a shorthand that will be expanded by the compiler to become accessor/mutator methods that adhere to the key value coding (KVC) standards. It's just a quick way of making sure you're KVC compliant since there's reduced opportunity for typographical errors - which are the bane of all Cocoa developers.

Comment: Properties aren't required for Interface Builder.  That's where the IBOutlet keyword comes in.

Answer (score 2):

- what is `statusText` ?

`statusText` is a `UILabel` in your code example

- Is it an `IBOutlet` or a `UILabel`?

Both.

`UILabel` is a type (a pointer to `UILabel` component that you use in GUI)

`IBOutlet` marks variable for Interface Builder application, so that it knows to show it as Outlet. During compilation IBOutlet is compiled out, it is defined in NSNibDeclarations.h as:

`#define IBOutlet`

- How does `@property
  (retain,nonatomic) UILabel
  *statusText` work?

You can create accessors (getters/setters) for a variable by hand, no need to use property. You can just have `UILabel *statusText` and implement your getter/setters by hand.

You can have accessors declared by compiler by defining variable as a `@property` and then either use `@synthesize` to create accessors in `.m` file or again you declare the accessors yourself (you can override default accessors that would be generated)

You can have `readwrite` or `readonly` property - meaning either both setter and getter gets generated or only getter.

You can use `copy`, `retain` or `assign` for setter (see more about memory management about the tree optons copy/retain/assign)

There are some other options like nonatomic/atomic which has to do with generating mutexes and lock variable before access and so on (see more [about properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1))

For example if you have variable

`NSString * string;`

defining it as readwrite property and then synthesising you get the compiler to generate for you:

```
@property (copy, readwrite) NSString * string
```

then using

```
@synthesize string;
```

generates something like:

```
- (NSString *) string
{
    return string;
}

- (void)setString:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString * copy = [str copy];
    [string release];
    string = copy;
}
```

- Does that statement mean that
     `statusText` is a property???

Yes you defined it as a property as explained above.

There are couple of concepts involved here.
Definition of variable, defining it as IBOutlet for Interface Builder, declare variables as properties so that compiler generates getters/setters for you, defining type of getters/setters such as access method, memory management and locking.

I hope this explains your questions and if you follow the link you will find the explanation by Apple which I believe is quite clear about how to use properties.

Sorry for the horrible formatting ...

Answer (score 0):

If you put IBOutlet in there like that, it will allow you to link the item while you're in interface builder.

Once you have the IBOutlet setup, you can open that class's nib and then select the File's Owner, then go to the inspector and drag a link from the Connections tab to the object.

This let's you then make changes to the object in your class's code and it will change the linked object. So once you link "statusText" to a specific UILabel, you can then use `statusText.text = @"new text"` in your class's code to modify the item, for example.

Also, IBAction allows you to make links in the same way. You can drag a connection from a control's event to the file owner and then select any method within that class that has IBAction as a return value.

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact two `statusText` "things" in your example. There is a `statusText` object of type UILabel, and there is a `statusText` function created by `@synthesize`. When you use `statusText` from inside a method you are reffering to the object, not the function. Use `self.statusText` to use the property/function.

Comment: Technically, a method, not a function. /quibble